# How to select a input with name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I need to select a radio input with name and value in jquery

In this example how you select element with name `SiblingSex` and value `female`

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio"  name="SiblingSex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio"  name="SiblingSex" value="female">Female


<input type="radio"  name="ParentSex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio"  name="ParentSex" value="female">Female

</form>
```

i need some thing like

```
$('input[name="SiblingSex"]' /*GENDER SELECTOR */)
```

Comment: Doing such a thing doesn't make any sense! you're getting value with `val()` Why do you need it as a selector?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak it seems to me OP just want to have `female value of SiblingSex` not from `female from ParentSex`.

Comment: @Jai If it is then only the `name` selector is enough! isn't it?

Comment: but that would get you the male value too.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Ofcourse i dont want to get the val , it just a example, i have been edited the question

Comment: @Jai we can check value using `:checked`!

Comment: I think you should propose it to OP that's what he wants i think.

Comment: @vimalraj.S if that was  an example then would you ask your question?

Comment: @jai My actual problem in a very big tedious html tree , Just to explain simply i asked this

Comment: @vimalraj.s its okay but i think your issue was just that you were making your selector little differently, nonetheless you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another attribute selector with this:

```
$('input[name="SiblingSex"][value="female"]').val();
```

the above line would give you values every time whether it is checked or not.

so if you only want to have the value when it is checked too then add `:checked`

```
$('input[name="SiblingSex"][value="female"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Nice , Its working , i was trying some thing like `$('input[name="SiblingSex",value="female"]').val()` , i missed []

Comment: @vimalraj.s you should also add `:checked` too.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look on the Demo on my [JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/JqPn2/1/)

Shows the two scenario:

```
1) when you want the value without selecting radio button.


2) when you want value after selecting radio button.
```

or may be the thing that you want is here::

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/JqPn2/2/)